# Concatenate wav files ignore if # channels is 2

Tags: bash, macos, audio, terminal, sox

I need to concatenate all the wav files in a folder.

I tried using the command

```
sox folder_name/*.wav folder_name.wav
```

But got the error

> ```
> sox FAIL sox: Input files must have the same # channels
> ```

Turns out only 21 of 2864 wav files in that folder have 2 channels instead of 1.

How can I just ignore the 21 files with 2 channels and concatenate all the 2843 wavs with 1 channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `soxi` to get all one channel files, put them in an array and then call `sox`:

```
for file in folder_name/*.wav; do
  if soxi "$file" | grep -q 'Channel.*1'; then
    files+=("$file")
  fi
done

sox "${files[@]}" folder_name.wav
```

Comment: This does it the wrong way around, I want all the 1-channel files merged. I can just select those though can't I?

Comment: Could you use the `soxi`'s `-c` option?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know it existed